# Jquery UI Autocomplete, select next input after get respone

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I like select the two inputbox after the automplete box.
The problem is that can not be select inputboxes after the autocomlete.

```
<script>
$('.autocomplete').die('focus').live('focus', function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: 'handler.php?event=autocomplete',
        delay: 500,
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).attr({"rel" : ui.item.id, "title" : ui.item.title});
            $.post('handler.php?event=get_details', 'id='+ui.item.id, function(ret){
                $(this).next('input').val(ret.unit);
                $(this).next('input').val(ret.min_amount);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="item[]" size="30" value="" class="autocomplete" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="unit[]" size="1" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="min_amount[]" size="5" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="item[]" size="30" value="" class="autocomplete" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="unit[]" size="1" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="min_amount[]" size="5" value=""></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this)
   .parent()
   .next()
   .children('input')
   .val(ret.unit)
   .end()
   .next()
   .children('input')
   .val(ret.min_amount);
```